# Create a border around a blob of pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a function that generates a binary mask of a single 'blob' that looks something like this:

[image]

(Note: This mask is generated by finding the convex hull of a series of points. My 'border finding' function has access to both the points used to generate the convex hull)

I want to set the values of the black pixels directly next to the white pixels to a specific value, creating a 'border'.

[image]

I tried edge detection with the following code: `cv2.Canny(image, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)`, as well as blurring the original mask to create a new mask, but neither gave the desired the results.

The only successful way of doing this I found was to brute force it.

```py
pos = np.where(image > 0)

for x, y in zip(pos[1], pos[0]):
    neighbours = [(y, x - min(x, 1)), (y, x + min(image.shape[1] - 1 - x, 1)), (y - min(y, 1), x), (y + min(image.shape[0] - 1 - y, 1), x)]
    for a, b in neighbours:
        if image[a, b] == 0:
            image[a, b] = 100
```

Is there a way to use Cv2 to achieve the same result?

Comment: You can do a [dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) and take the difference against the original.

Comment: do not use Canny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code finds and draws the contour of pixels with a value of 255 on the input image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Read input image 
input_image = cv2.imread("input.png",0)
#Copy for output image
output_image = cv2.imread("input.png")

#Check Unique values and image size
#print(np.unique(input_image)) #=> [0,255]
#print(input_image.shape) #=>(22, 22, 3)

#Found the values present in image is 0 and 255, filter out any values other than 255.
mask_filetred = cv2.inRange(input_image, 254, 255)
#Find the countour of pixels with value 255
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_filetred, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#print(contours) #=> countour list

#Draw the contour on 'output_image' i.e. copy of input image.
cv2.drawContours(output_image, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 1)
# Save output image to 'output.png'
cv2.imwrite('output.png',output_image)
```

> input image

[image]

> output image

[image]